# How can I multiple filter array in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I can only filter with search text input. but I want to use 2 select dropdown + text input while filtering the array. how can I include dropdowns into the filter?

basically, when the user selects location and search something, I just wan't to show results from that selected location. thank you for your help!

```js
import Select from "react-select";

const Positions = ({ positions }: DataProps) => {

  const locations: any = [
    { value: "canada", label: "Canada" },
    { value: "italy", label: "Italy" },
    { value: "france", label: "France" },
  ];

  const jobs: any = [
    { value: "uidesigner", label: "UI Designer" },
    { value: "back-end", label: "Backend Developer" },
    { value: "frontend", label: "Frontend Developer" },
  ];

  const [selectLocation, setSelectLocation] = useState<any>("");
  const [selectJobType, setSelectJobType] = useState<any>("");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<any>("");

  return (   
                  <input
                    type="search"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                  />
      
                <Select
                  defaultValue={selectLocation}
                  onChange={setSelectLocation}
                  options={locations}
                  instanceId={"1"}
                  placeholder="Location"
                />
              </div>

         
                <Select
                  defaultValue={selectJobType}
                  onChange={setSelectJobType}
                  options={jobs}
                  placeholder="Job Type"
                  instanceId={"2"}
                />
   
            {positions?.map((position: any) => (
              <SinglePosition
                category={position.category}
                type={position.type}
                location={position.location}
                position={position.position}
                key={position._id}
              />
            ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a "list" for the result of filtering the "positions" like this:

```js
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<any>("");
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

then a "useEffect" to change this list every time you change one of the search inputs from the original list:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if(positions.length > 0) {
     let newList = [...positions];
     if(searchTerm) {
        newList = newList.filter(i => i.XXX === searchTerm);
     }
     if(selectJobType) {
        newList = newList.filter(i => i.XXX === selectJobType);
     }
     if(selectPosition) {
        newList = newList.filter(i => i.XXX === selectPosition);
     }
     setFiltered(newList);
  }
}, [positions, searchTerm, selectJobType, selectPosition]);
```

Then use this "filtered" list to map in your "SinglePosition" instead of "postions"

Comment: thank you! but can I show results while typing search input? like I have to type Back-End Developer to get results but can I show it by just typing "back"

Comment: You can filter as you want, you only need to adjust the right precicate inside each "filter" (I am not sure if I got what you wrote, but maybe compare after to lowercase both strings will be enough). If you want to filter while typing considerer to look for debounce the function to change the filtered list.